# How to use shiny javascript functions with modules?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to include some javascript in my shiny module, but regardles of what I tried the javascript is not appear in the final app. What am I doing wrong?

App.r:

```
    library(shiny)
    source("examplemod.R")
    ui <- fluidPage(
      tags$head(
        tags$script(src="shinyjavascript.js")
      ),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          examplemodUI("example")
        ),
        mainPanel(

        )
      )
    )

    server <- function(input, output) {
      callModule(examplemod, "example")


    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Module:

```
   examplemodUI<-function(id){
      ns <- NS(id)

      tagList(

        textOutput(ns("prb"))

      ) 
    }

    examplemod<- function(input, output, session) {

      output$prb<-renderPrint({

        input$one

        })
    }
```

shinyjavascript.js

```
    $( document ).on("shiny:sessioninitialized", function(event) {
         Shiny.onInputChange("one", "noone");           
       });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, check that your `shinyjavascript.js` can be found by the browser. Run your add and open it in a browser. Chrome has a better inspector module than RStudio's built in app viewer (the one that pops up when you run an app). In the browser's Inspector, find the reference to `shinyjavascript.js` both in the "Elements" pane and that the contents can be loaded in the "Sources" pane.

If it's there, but cannot be loaded, ensure that the file is placed in a subdirectory `www` from where your app's R source files are located.

If the file is found and loaded, update it to the following for some good ol' fashioned debugging:

```
console.log('JavaScript file loaded')
$( document ).on("shiny:sessioninitialized", function(event) {
     console.log('session initialized')
     Shiny.onInputChange("one", "noone");           
   });
```

Reload the page and look for these two lines in the console. This will give us a hint to how far your code runs.

**Update:**

Once satisfied your javascript is loaded and running, we move on to the next. Does your app receive the value and why doesn't it update?

`output$prb<-renderPrint` is a reactive that only executes *if and only if* Shiny as `prb` binded to an output control. This could be your case, or it's that `input$one` doesn't work. So, we separate the two.

Try to update the following:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  callModule(examplemod, "example")

  observe({cat(input$one, '\n')})
}
```

This should print 'noone' to the **R** console.

If that works, move the new `observe` line to your module:

```
examplemod<- function(input, output, session) {
  output$prb<-renderPrint({
    input$one
    })
  observe({cat(input$one, '\n')})
}
```

and see if you get a response there.

**Update 2 with solution:**

So, I've detailed how I would debug these problems. But have found a solution. It requires 3 small changes:

```
 examplemod<- function(input, output, session, one) {   # 1

  output$prb<-renderPrint({
    one()                                               # 2
    })

 callModule(examplemod, "example", reactive(input$one)) # 3
```

But I cannot offer any explanation as to why you cannot use `input` directly...

Comment: I have tried and both "Javascript file loaded" and "session initialized" texts are printed on the console.log

Comment: So, the JavaScript is working. See my update for the next step.